# A rather odd Crate of Haikus

Tags: riddle, poetry, odd-one-out

1:

> If you're positive,
>
> I'm so super attractive-
>
> My flow is current.

2:

> I am a high spy,
>
> Or a big help on the road.
>
> I can be for Sky.

3:

> Typical package,
>
> You can do me in a ring,
>
> But I'm just a square

4:

> Rock, or metallic?
>
> Holder of keys, or your vows,
>
> Or maybe a sound?

Once you've solved all four riddles, you may spot a pattern among three of the answers, but one of the answers is an anomaly, which one is it?

Comment: #2 isn't a true haiku, since the first line only has 4 syllables. COINCIDENCE?  MISTAKE? CLUE?? You be the judge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're positive,
I'm so super attractive-
My flow is current.

> Electron: Negatively charged- so attracted to positive, flow is called Current

I am high spy,
Or a big help on the road.
I can be for Sky.

> Satellite: Spy Sats, GPS, Sky Radio XM

Typical package,
You can do me in a ring,
But I'm just a square

> Box: Present Box,Boxing Ring, 2d box

Rock, or metallic?
Holder of keys, or your vows,
Or maybe a sound?

> Ring: Diamond/Gold, Keyring/Wedding Ring/ Bell rings

I think the one that doesn't fit is

> Box, because the rest could reference orbitals, this also link to the title as a crate is a box.

Comment: We have a winner!

Comment: Uh beat me :P Well done!

Comment: Also maybe 'Crate' in the title indicates that the box is the odd one out? @Melkor can say if thats right

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil that's correct

Comment: Are you going to accept this?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure 1 is:

> An electron

If you're positive,
I'm so super attractive-
My flow is current.

> Electrons are attracted to positively charged protons, they are negative and there is a minus sign at the end of the 2nd line, and they flow to produce electricity.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

First haiku

> Answer is surely ELECTRON. (Electrons are negatively charged and hence attractive to positively charged things, their flow forms electric currents).

Second haiku

> Must be SATELLITE (spy satellites, GPS, satellite TV).

Third haiku

> (Still thinking about this one.)

Fourth haiku

> Answer is probably RING ("rock" perhaps a reference to neolithic stone circles, but I think I'm missing something here; "metallic" because of jewelry); second line refers to key rings and wedding rings; fourth to the ringing sound made by, e.g., bells.

[I am no longer attempting to improve this partial answer because Sconibulus posted a complete answer that agrees with the parts I had, and I'm pretty sure his answer is entirely correct.]